# Chrome Extension - Send form input value to mysql-db on altervista

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I am developing a chrome extension that scrapes data from a site, inserts the values ​​in an html form (in the `popup.html` through `background.js` and `popus.js`).

I need to send this data from the form in `popup.html` to the external mysql database (altervista). Due to chrome cps the normal php form does not work.

How can I proceed? I read about ajax api + jquery, could you show me some examples applied to an html form? Thanks a lot to everyone.

My situation:

1. `Background.js` collect data from console/site by scrape (OK)
2. `Popup.js` get data from `Background.js` and update `popup.html` with data (OK)
3. `Popup.html` have data visible but with form I don't to send to mysql on AV (NOK)